# Cast to string failed for array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I'm trying to create a document from the elements of an array but it constantly throws `Document Validation Error`.

The schema is like this:

```
userId: String,
terms: [{
  value: String,
  system: String
}],
group: String
```

I have an array of `values` for `terms`, `['hello', 'hey', 'hi']`

Now, I want to be able to `create` a document using the `values` from the array like this:

```
{
  userId: 'foo',
  terms: [{value: 'hello'}, {value: 'hey'}, {value: 'hi'}],
  group: 'bar'
}
```

The way I'm trying to do it but failing:

```
let arr = ['hello', 'hey', 'hi'];
Document.create({userId: 'somevalue', terms: {value: {$in: arr}}}) // validation error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
let arr = ['hello', 'hey', 'hi'];
Document.create({
  userId: 'somevalue',
  terms: arr.map(value => ({ value }) )
})
```

That will actually transform the array content as:

```
[{value: 'hello'}, {value: 'hey'}, {value: 'hi'}]
```

and use that value as you create the document.